# Changing excel's upper context menu (the one with format options)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change context menu items using VBA, similar to this [Microsoft's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862(v=office.14).aspx) for my application yet, that one!

[image: Image to rescue my sorryass english]

The end user will be attending to a line of customers and adding products to their, let's say, virtual "shopping cart".

This "shop" has very limited items on sale and they would fit easily on the context menu and by clicking on then the user would add each item in a very 'well behaved' manner. Yet, I'm trying to make things a little faster, editing not only the main context menu (as explained on posted MS docs), but editing the upper as well.
It's a little improvement on the user side, as items will be closer to the cursor.

So, this question refers to "how-to", but any help, even the name of this menu, would be appreciated.
It's easier to find documentation when you know the names of stuff.

Comment: Do you want to add sale items to the right click popup menu in Excel?  If so then try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413777/add-a-macro-to-the-right-button-menu. --- Be sure to put the kill code in the "thisworkbook" module under the onClose sub.

Comment: This one is exactly as described in the link I posted. What I really want is to add buttons on the format options listed above the right click menu. But thanks!

Comment: Like this?    http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-assign-macros-to-the-ribbon-and-the-quick-access-toolbar-in-excel-2013/

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add an option to the ribbon with VBA, but you can do it manually.  http://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/12/03/add-your-personal-excel-macros-to-the-ribbon/

Comment: @JohnMuggins Not exactly, but hey, this second link gave me an really interesting alternative. Will give it a shot and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: another option might be to create a userform with the options you want and set it to `vbModeless`, so that you can interact with the sheet and the userform at the same time

Comment: @ballsy26 Yup, been there. It was my first option but I've discarded it. Dates got messed up in a very random way, I mean, Brazilian standard is DDMMYY and VBA insists on MMDDYY on a few cases, even using cdate to handle then. As the reports are date based(weekly, monthly or daily) and the results weren't consistent, I had to discard it. Thanks anyway!